# Can't print any more "Stopped - Filter failed"

Tags: usb, printing

I have a HP DeskJet 940c.
It had always worked.

A few days ago it has suddenly stopped working. Even after reboot, its status ("Printer State") always shows "Stopped - Filter failed" and every time I try to print the job remains "pending" forever.

I have rebooted several times.

Is there any known fix/workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the printer worked before. Check your `/var/spool/cups` directory, and empty it.

If that does not help, see the instructions for install the necessary plugins for your HP printer [here](http://hplipopensource.com/node/309).

Comment: Yes it worked before as I said.
After emptying /var/spool/cups, and reconnecting the printer, the issue persists. These errors appeared in /var/log/cups/error_log when I connected the printer:
W [18/Nov/2013:19:35:59 +0100] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_hp
W [18/Nov/2013:19:35:59 +0100] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_hp

Comment: Why should I suddenly need to install a plugin for a printer that was working? Just asking. Did I have the plugin and it got uninstalled or corrupted somehow? Is it some broken update that makes the printer need a plugin that it didn't use to need but doesn't either automatically install it nor issue a warning?

Comment: Ok, hp-setup fixed the issue. It created a new printer, I deleted the old one, and the new one works. Ridiculous.

Comment: For me this solution doesn't work

Comment: When using `sudo hp-setup` I had an error: "Printer queue setup failed". `sudo hp-setup -i` helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Im my case, it was due to missing libraries as shown by cups error log fragment:

```
D [07/Apr/2014:18:42:50 -0300] [Job 6] /usr/lib/cups/filter/watermarkfilter: error while loading shared libraries: libcupsimage.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
D [07/Apr/2014:18:42:50 -0300] [Job 6] /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoprinterbin: error while loading shared libraries: libcupsimage.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Pay attention if your printer driver is 32 or 64 bit, so you should install the right libraries arch.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, one of my kids borrowed the USB cord. Ubuntu didn't seem to know this. After I uninstalled the printer driver, I noticed the cord missing. Replace cord and driver, now works fine

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was solved by restarting the print server:

```
sudo systemctl restart cups.service
```

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me out of the blue - yesterday the printer worked. I tried restarting the `cups` service, and tried restarting the machine, both didn't work. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

**What worked for me:**

I updated the installed software packages, after which the problem was gone.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem happened because I had restarted the router and the IP address of the printer had changed. I went into the printer configuration in Ubuntu and updated the IP address (which I took from the printer's Network Summary printout) and it worked again after that.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in the comments, removing the printer and adding it again worked for me.

I did empty the var/spool/cups directory before, but I don't know if this deletion had an impact. I didn't use the HP Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Start a print job, look into the cups error logs:

```
sudo tail -n 100 -f /var/log/cups/error_log
```

Check if it is failing due to a missing library. In my case I saw the error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libcupsimage.so.2: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

To find the missing library:

```
$ apt-file search libcupsimage.so.2
libcupsimage2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcupsimage.so.2
```

Install the missing library, and re-run a test print:

```
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2
```

Even if that fails, your driver might require 32-bit libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the printer in system settings and re-installing it using the HP Device Manager fixed the problem for me.